# What distros have rpm but not systemd?

Tags: linux-distribution, operating-system, package-manager

This is a similar question to [this one](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/36157/linux-distributions-which-do-not-default-to-using-systemd), but with the additional requirement that it uses a rpm-based package manager such as `dnf` or `yum`. Like that poster, I have grown to dislike systemd, but I've also grown to appreciate some of the features that rpm-based package managers provide over apt-based ones, along with its general user experience. (so the rpm thing is half technical requirement, half preference)

I'd prefer if it wasn't systemd by default, but the distro qualifies if I don't have to edit init files to get updates or installs to work (unless I want to ), and if it's using mostly rpm packages out of the box. (ex: a system that mostly uses snap flatpak or appimage over rpm is a no-go. Another example would be a system that uses systemd by default but it's easy to change to something else, usually at install: this one's good.)

> Aside: Yes, I'm aware that rpm is maintained by the very same RedHat that has cursed us with systemd, but I feel that doesn't warrant labeling all RH software as bloated or with stupid defaults, but it does merit additional research.

Lastly, I'm not asking to use sysVinit. I'd prefer s6, OpenRC, runit or others.

Comment: It seems like PCLinuxOS is close to what I'm looking for, but it uses sysVinit.

Comment: After more searching, I found [PLD linux](https://pld-linux.org/). It's been around since 1998. It seems to only support sysVinit